# Default documents in web.xml not being respected (developer/stand-alone server)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

For some reason, when browsing to URL that ends in a folder (ex. //localhost:8500/website/directory/), index.cfm is not loading and instead a 404 error page is returned. I have confirmed that the ...\web-inf\web.xml file is being used by modifying filter-mappings to enable the display of .htm and .txt files. In fact, none of the files in the welcome-file-list section are being used even if they exist which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with this section of the web.xml file.

The web.xml files are as follows:

- {install-root}\cfusion\runtime\conf\web.xml
- {install-root}\cfusion\wwwroot\web-inf\web.xml

Both files contain the same XML listed below.

> ```
> <web-app>
> ...
> <welcome-file-list id="WelcomeFileList_1034013110672">
>     <welcome-file>index.cfm</welcome-file>
>     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
>     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
>     <welcome-file>index.txt</welcome-file>
> </welcome-file-list>
> ...
> </web-app>
> ```

I have just recently patched to Update 6, but I believe that the problem was always there from the initial install. Please note that this is the development stand-alone server.

Has anyone already solved this or have any ideas on how to proceed other than re-installing CF10 and using IIS?

Comment: I don't see index.txt here. Also, the {install}/cfusion/runtime/conf/web.xml is different (just index.html,index.htm,index.jsp - no index.cfm)

Comment: Are the welcome files respected if you hit the site via the Tomcat web server instead of IIS? What default files have you got listed in IIS?

Comment: My default install on MacOS has:    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

Comment: @PeterBoughton - I manually added the index.txt to see if it would allow non CF parsed files. It doesn't matter what keys are there, the Tomcat server doesn't appear to be using them.

Comment: @AdamCameron - I'm trying not to use IIS. This is all running on the stand-alone server that comes with the developer edition which I'm using on my local development machine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the correct file and the correct place to add these entries, it's just that the stand-alone version of ColdFusion server (which, I believe is TomCat) is not importing and/or using either of the welcome-file-list sections of either web.xml document.

Comment: Just wondering, is this CF server ALSO connected to IIS or Apache?  If so, the built in server may be disabled.

Comment: @DougHughes I do have both Apache and IIS installed, but my Apache monitor does not show that it is running and I only run IIS when I need it for other types of development. To my knowledge, my stand-along server is NOT connected to either, but I don't know how to check.

Comment: If you look under {install-root}/config/wsconfig, do you see a directory named "1" and probably two other files wsconfig.log and wsconfig.properties?  

If so, please check the wsconfig.properties file and see what's in it.  The wsconfig.log file would also have the details of any connections you've made.

All that said, I suspect that's not the issue.  Can you get to the CF admin on port 8500? http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator?

Comment: @DougHughes Inside of {install-root}/config/wsconfig I only have cfwin32.dll and wsconfig.log with no sub-folders. I am able to access CF admin and any CF files so long as the URLs end in a cffile like index.cfm, etc. That being said, the URL you asked about results in a 404, but if I specify index.cfm, it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to share your entire web.xml files?  I'd like to compare them against mine to see what's different.  That said, I'm connected to Apache and my built in server is (apparently) not running.

Comment: I think I'm just going to uninstall and re-install using IIS. The upside to this is that I'll be in sync with our other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, IMO there are two possible reasons that i can think of for this issue

- Either your have additional mapping like "/" in place which is taking over servletcontainer's builtin default servlet who is the one responsible for going to the right root path
- your folder name is something which CF already have a mapping for e.g. /flashservices/gateway/, CFFormGateway, cfform-internal, WSRPProducer, JSDebugServlet, flex2gateway

I think sharing your web.xml could have helped pin point the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and it was a case-sensitivity issue in Tomcat (despite this being a ColdFusion 10 install on Windows).

My default index.cfm would load when I navigated to http://127.0.0.1 but as soon as I went to http://127.0.0.1/mysite, I got a 404.  The folder was named mySite in Windows.  As soon as I changed my URL to http://127.0.0.1/mySite it began working.